# For loop 1a ,2b, 3c... in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am learning how `for` loops work. I need to print the values

> ```
> 1a 2b 3c
> ```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
int [] numbers ={1, 2, 3};
String [] letters = {"a","b","c"};
for (int n: numbers){
    for( String l:letters){
        Log.i("sas","Result    " + n +l);
    }
}
```

This code is obviously not working. It gave me

> ```
> 1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c 3a 3b 3c
> ```

How can I fix the loop to give a result of `1a 2b 3c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need two nested loops, you need one loop iterating both arrays at the same time:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < Math.min(numbers.length, letters.length) ; i++) {
    Log.i("sas","Result    " + numbers[i] + letters[i]);
}
```

If you are certain that both arrays have the same number of elements, you could use `length` of one of them (i.e. `numbers.length` or `letters.length`, it does not matter since they are equal) for the stopping condition of your `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you man, that what i need, i have to wait 10 min to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i< numbers.length(); i++){
        Log.i("sas","Result    " + numbers[i] +letters[i]);
 }
```

Assuming that sizes of two arrays will be same and you want to attach corresponding items together